# Compute this sum $\sum\limits_{i=3}^n \binom{n}{i} \frac{i!2^{i-3}}{(i-3)!}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I'm having problems calculating this:

$$\sum_{i=3}^n \binom{n}{i} \frac{i!2^{i-3}}{(i-3)!}$$

I got that it equals to $3^n$ but it's not the correct answer.

P.S. If it is necessary I can provide my wrong calculation.

Comment: $$\binom{n}{i} \frac{i!2^{i-3}}{(i-3)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\binom{n-3}{i-3} 2^{i-3}$$

Comment: Playing off @Did 's comment: $\sum_{i=3} ^n \binom{n-3}{i-3} 2^{i-3} = \sum_{i=0} ^{n-3} \binom{n-3}{i} 2^{i} 1^{n-3-i}$

Comment: @Kitter Catter You forgot to multiply by $n(n-1)(n-2)$

Comment: I just didn't want to lug that around. That term passes through the sum on $i$ so it is a bit irrelevant to making a hint.

Comment: To the asker: You should probably provide your wrong calculation so we can help locate where you went wrong and why. It couldn't hurt we don't bite.

Comment: @Did The RHS part was too fast. Can you make more equations to make it simpler? My binom's knowledge isn't so good..

Comment: If that is the case, in a true educational spirit (not to be confused with geese forcefeeding), I suggest that you spend 5 minutes (re)viewing the basics of the binomial coefficients -- if only to understand why the hint in my comment suffices to solve completely the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I like combinatorial arguments:

You have a box of white balls numbered $1$ through $n$. You pick at least $3$ of these balls and paint them red. Then you select $3$ of the red balls and line them up on the table. Finally, you paint a gold star on any subset of the remaining red balls and throw all of the balls back into the box except the $3$ red ones lined up on the table. How many different outcomes are possible?

If you initially pick $k$ balls to paint red, there are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose them. Once you have them, there are

$$k(k-1)(k-2)=\frac{k!}{(k-3)!}$$

ways to choose $3$ of the $k$ red balls and line them up. Finally, there are $2^{k-3}$ ways to choose a subset of the remaining red balls to receive gold stars. The total number of outcomes with $k$ red balls is therefore

$$\binom{n}k\frac{k!2^{k-3}}{(k-3)!}\;,$$

and since the possible values of $k$ are $3,4,\ldots,n$, the total number of possible outcomes is

$$\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k!2^{k-3}}{(k-3)!}\;.$$

On the other hand, we can get exactly the same set of outcomes by a much simpler procedure. First pick $3$ balls, paint them red, and line them up on the table; this can be done in $n(n-1)(n-2)$ ways. Then divide the remaining $n-3$ balls into $3$ sets, say $W,R$, and $S$, do nothing to the balls in $W$, paint the balls in $R$ and $S$ red, and paint a gold star on the balls in $S$. (Any of these three sets can be empty, but every ball must be in exactly one of them.) This step is just making a $3$-way choice of sets for each of $n-3$ balls, so it can be carried out in $3^{n-3}$ different ways. Thus, the number of possible outcomes is $n(n-1)(n-2)3^{n-3}$, and we have

$$\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k!2^{k-3}}{(k-3)!}=n(n-1)(n-2)3^{n-3}=\frac{n!3^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}\;.$$

Comment: Nice creativity Brian!

Comment: @Ilan: Thanks! $\,$

Answer (score 3):

Expanding Did's comment,
$$n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{i=3}^{n}\binom{n-3}{i-3}2^{i-3}=n(n-1)(n-2)\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{k}2^k = n(n-1)(n-2)(1+2)^{n-3}=\color{red}{n(n-1)(n-2)3^{n-3}}.$$